Docker Oracle Database 19c non-CDB recreate itself at every restart, how to prevent it?
I'm running Oracle Database 19c in a Docker container. I've mounted the database files to persistent storage on my host machine, but every time I restart the container, Oracle seems to recreate the database, even though the necessary files already exist on the host.
Moreover, at the end of the database setup, I received this error:
#####################################

########### E R R O R ###############

DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!

Please check output for further info!

########### E R R O R ###############

#####################################

The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
However i can connect to the database and check the instance with sqlplus
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I tried several things in order to install the database:

using the docker image : container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0 :
I started the image in sleep mode, retrieved the dbca.rsp.tmpl and createDB.sh files.
I modified these two files for a non-CDB installation.
Then, I created a Docker image with a docker file of my own to replace the original files with mine.

using the installation found here : https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0
Try a first install without any changes : the database is a CDB Database
Try to modify dbca.rsp.tmpl and createDB.sh, rebuild the image with the dockerfile included
same results.



I can give you the files I used, feel free to ask for more information.
